# Exception when starting Spark shell on Windows 7

Tags: windows, scala, shell, exception, apache-spark

I am failing to manage to get the Scala Spark shell to run correctly on Windows 7.

Whenever I start it, I get the following error: `The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-`

I've been through many SO answers and a few blogs, but so far nothing has helped.

I'm running Spark 2.1.0. I have `%HADOOP_HOME%` set to a directory, and I have `winutils.exe` in `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`.

Spark is at `c:\Spark` (no sub directory) and `%SPARK_HOME%` is set to that directory.

`c:\tmp\hive` has 777 permissions, as shown if I run `winutils ls tmp`.

Testing the directory for write permission from the shell shows that it's writable. See here:

```
scala> import java.io.File                               
import java.io.File                                                              

scala> val f = new File("/tmp")                          
f: java.io.File = \tmp                                   

scala> f.canWrite()                                      
res0: Boolean = true                                     

scala> val f2 = new File("/tmp/hive")                    
f2: java.io.File = \tmp\hive                             

scala> f2.canWrite()                                     
res1: Boolean = true
```

sbt is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\` and `%SBT_HOME%` is set to that directory.

`%JAVA_HOME%` is set to `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\`.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;`, `%SPARK_HOME%\bin;` and `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;` are in the path.

I am running the shell from the command line, running as administrator.

After everything load and the exception is thrown, none of the spark libraries are loaded and `sc` is not available.

What am I doing wrong?